# How to exclude deserialization of objects from Json array within' GSON?

Tags: android, json, gson

In Android app I'm working with ["Pokemon API Service"](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/), where JSON-responses is parsed within' GSON library. In response I have the following array of pokemon's stats objects:

```
stats":[  
   {  
      "stat":{  
         "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/stat\/6\/",
         "name":"speed"
      },
      "effort":2,
      "base_stat":90
   },
   {  
      "stat":{  
         "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/stat\/5\/",
         "name":"special-defense",

      },
      "effort":0,
      "base_stat":50
   },
   {  
      "stat":{  
         "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/stat\/4\/",
         "name":"special-attack"
      },
      "effort":0,
      "base_stat":50
   },
   {  
      "stat":{  
         "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/stat\/3\/",
         "name":"defense"
      },
      "effort":0,
      "base_stat":40
   },
   {  
      "stat":{  
         "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/stat\/2\/",
         "name":"attack"
      },
      "effort":0,
      "base_stat":55
   },
   {  
      "stat":{  
         "url":"https:\/\/pokeapi.co\/api\/v2\/stat\/1\/",
         "name":"hp"
      },
      "effort":0,
      "base_stat":35
   }
]
```

In my case I need only three last objects where nested stat objects have names "defense", "hp", "attack". I want to exclude from deserialization objects with "speed", "special-defence" and "special-attack", because I don't need this data. So I want to know: is possible do deserialize Json arrays selectivly or not? If the answer is yes how can I achieve this within GSON library?

P.S.

For this situation I've designed such POJO-classes:

```
public class Shocase {
  List<StatsItem> stats;
}

class StatsItem{
  private Stat stat;
  private int effort;
  private int baseStat;
}

class Stat{
  private String url;
  private String name;
}
```

Comment: Then simply dont add then in the class your parsing then in..

Comment: Look at post changes. I've added POJO-classes. As I understand by default all array-items will be automatically added into list.

Comment: Can you clarify your question first.. If you dont need the data then dont parse them. Thats all. I dont understand the problem with that.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. As I understand for the desearilization of Json array I need to make some Array or List container (List<StatsItem> stats). The response Json array (stats:[]) contains 6 items. From this 6 I need only three last ones where "stat" objects have names "attack" "defense" and "hp". But when I parse this respone with GSON useless first three items are also getting into container as a part of one array. So I'm trying to figure out how to avoid and get from Json array only three last items,

Comment: I understand your question better now. Theres no way for you to not parse those selective items only. GSON will parse all of those items. There is no way to tell GSON to parse only specific items. If you really dont want to parse them I suggest you do the parsing by yourself.